# CakePHP Can validations be used in controllers and then omitted during create/update?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I've set up a few validations as examples that check in the controller that the requested information of a post is correct.  Just a bunch of simple validations like minlength, notBlank, etc; and this all works.  Some of the fields are not for use when saving or updating though, and I only want to validate them in the request then forget about them.

For example on change password the current, new and confirm passwords are submitted in the request, and they should all be required among other things, but if set them to notBlank that means they are in the data used for the update, but only the new password should be required there, while the other two after validation are no longer needed.

I know I can call a subset of the validations in my controller, but I also noticed that the validations don't appear to specific to a particular save/update they are model wide so it seems like you can't just have validations that are used just outside save/update for requests.

Is there a way to do this in CakePHP?  Was hoping this would work similar to Laravel's 5.x requests.

Comment: You can also dynamically change the rule set (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules). So you could remove the `notBlank` rule before saving the update.

Comment: Also, `notBlank` was added in 2.7 so you shouldn't be using it with CakePHP 2.4 (use `notEmpty` instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can validate the data without saving it and then save it without validating. To validate use the Model::validates() method, for example:

```
$this->YourModel->set($this->request->data);
if($this->YourModel->validates()){
  //Logic if validation succeeded  
}else{
  //Logic if validation didn't succed
}
```

To save data without validation

```
$this->YoutModel->save(null,false);
```

If you check the cakephp api you could see that the save method can have three parameters, the data to save, the fields to validate or a boolean indicating whether to validate or not, and the fields to save.
More info here [CakePHP save method](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#_save) and here [CakePHP validation in Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)

Comment: Oh man I totally missed that in the save method I was overly focused in the model and controller validation sections, but not the model itself.  Cheers, that's perfect.